# Show tar.gz files but tar.gz is already inside a tar file

Tags: tar, aix, gzip

I want to see a tar.gz files that are inside a tar file.

So I have a tar file that has a tar.gz file inside and I want to see the tar.gz files without extraction my tar and my tar.gz.

So to explain more, inside my tar I have a tar.gz, File.tar -> File.tar.gz. so I need to see the files inside my tar.gz but my tar.gz is already inside my tar, and that without extracting my tar and also my tar.gz.

I tried this but doesn't work :
tar -xvf File.tar File2.tar.gz | gtar -ztvf -

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Hello again , inside my tar I have a tar.gz, File.tar -> File.tar.gz. so I need to see file inside my tar and inside my tar.gz that is already inside my tar .

Comment: It might help to use example filenames. As it stands, your explanation is not the clearest.

Comment: I have this file . File.tar inside this file you can find a file.tar.gz and other files , when I do a tar -tvf File.tar , I can see all the files : exemple : File1 and File2.tar.gz  but I want to see the files inside  File2.tar.gz . I know I can do something like tar -xvf File.tar -O File2.tar.gz.

Comment: Or something like that

Comment: Or I need to make a pipe or an exec.

Comment: Edit the question. Don't add stuff in comments. And use names other than 'file', it's clearer.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to run `tar -tf /path/to/file.tar.gz`, or `tar -tzf /path/to/file.tar.gz`.

As far as I've seen, you should avoid using `-tf`, and prefer `-tzf`: at least on BSD systems, forgetting the `z` gives:

```
tar: input compressed with gzip; use the -z option to decompress it
```

---

Following up on your comment, say you want to list the content of an archive inside an archive, ... Try this:

```
tar -zxOf /path/to/parent/archive.tar.gz path/to/packed/archive.tar.gz | tar -ztf -
```

With `path/to/packed/archive.tar.gz`, the path of your archive inside `/path/to/parent/archive.tar.gz`.

Comment: Doesn't work : and my parent package archive is a tar only not a tar.gz.

Comment: The option -O usually switches to old tar archive versions. You do not seem to speak about `tar` but probably about `gtar`.

Comment: The `-O` option is about writing tar output to stdout. My answer is about `tar`, the same you would find on BSD systems. The `tf`/`tzf` comment is however about `gtar` specifics, pointing out they are not standard thus should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions
you can use the command

```
tar -tvf filename.tar.gz
```

You can also use vim

```
vim filename.tar.gz
```

Comment: `vi` and it's clones do not support to edit binary files without destroying the content and a compressed tar archive is heavily binary.

Answer (score 0):

**_ for 1 level of taring _**

a portable solution to uncompress 'on the fly' and then have tar display the content:

```
gzip -dc - <file.tar.gz | tar tvf -
```

this is the pendant of the compression on the fly:

```
tar cf -  files and dirs | gzip -c - >newcompressedtarfile.tar.gz
```

(of course, with a recent (and usually GNU variant) tar you can just:   tar tzvf  file.tar  ... but the way above is portable, and can be generalised to many other scenarios (find infos inside files without ungzipping them first, etc)

**_ for you case: list the content of a .tar.gz that is inside a .tar _**

You will probably need the GNU version of tar and use the  `--to-stdout` (or **Capital O**, `-O`) optino to uncompress a file to stdout instead of creating it on disk:

```
# let's say Archive.tar contains file.tar.gz, 
{and you want the content of the latter without writing any files on disk

tar -xOf  archive.tar  file.tar.gz | gzip -dc - | tar tvf -
```

Comment: I can't do something like this :  <code> tar -xvf File.tar | gtar File2.tar.gz | tar -tvf - </code>?

Comment: I have this error : tar: illegal option -- O

Comment: The -O parameter is used only with tar.gz files not with a tar file.

Comment: @Issam : you specified Linux, so usually GNU tar, which should know -O (not for compressed files, that was the z option which I just edited out as the first tar file is not .gz).

Comment: The -O work for my tar.gz but not for my tar maybe because I am in Aix

Comment: @issam: If on aix, you should put `aix` instead of `linux` as tags for the question, otherwise you will get a plethora of gnu-only solutions (very common here to have non portable solutions relying on recent gnu tools, especially of the linux flavors). I edit the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

vim fnm.tar.gz or vim flnm.tgz
tar -tvzf fnm.tar.gz or tar -tvzf flnm.tgz

Both of these will help display the contents in the file. If you have a tar file inside of another tar file then thats a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Gnu tar has "--to-command'

```
tar xzf tarfile1.tar.gz pathto/tarfile2.tar.gz --to-command='tar tvzf -'
```

Anyway "-O" also works for you :

```
tar xzf tarfile1.tar.gz pathto/tarfile2.tar.gz -O | tar tvzf -
```